# rails does not render application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rendering

I am learning rails by working on a small project and I'm using rails 3.2.3.

I used nifty generator to create my model and layouts and clearance gem for the login.

Now when I go to the index page of my model, only the index page is rendered but not the application.html.erb in the layout. I tried adding

```
layout 'application'
```

in both the application controller and my model controller. But still doesn't help. Also when I click on delete, it takes me to the show page.

My application.html.erb looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= content_tag :h1, yield(:title) if show_title? %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even tried changing the javascript include tag to :defaults but still doesn't work.

Is someone facing the same situation ?

Comment: Is your `application.html.erb` located in `app/views/layouts/`?

Comment: does using a custom new method in my controller break the pages ?

Comment: I realized that this happens when I changed(removed some input boxes) my _form.html.erb and made changes the default create method in the controller.